# Parsing url,hashtags out of twitter text

Tags: excel, csv, parsing, twitter

I have already extracted all the tweets in csv file, I want to seperate twitter text from hashtags and urls, so far I have serarated the hashtags in excel using

> Data -> Text to Column

First I don't know how to separate urls using this method
Second is there a better way to do that? All the online links are separating both things at the time of scrapping

```
TEXT
Learned a new concept today : metamorphic testing.  http:/t.co/0is1IUs3aW
variant identification in pooled DNA using R http:/t.co/4PQfUaU
Meta-All: a system for managing metabolic pathway information http:/t.co/2PfJXUxq2X
```

Here is what it should look like

```
 TEXT                                                                 URL
  Learned a new concept today : metamorphic testing.                  http:/t.co/0is1IUs3aW
  variant identification in pooled DNA using R                        http:/t.co/4PQfUaU  
  Meta-All: a system for managing metabolic pathway information       http:/t.co/2PfJXUxq2X
```

Right now both the text and url are in one column I want to put them in different columns

Comment: You're unlikely to get any useful suggestions without a sample of the data you're working with, and a full description of exactly what you want to do with it.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hope it helps now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the URL from A2:     `=MID(A2,FIND("http",A2),500)`

The rest from A2:     `=MID(A2,1,FIND("http",A2)-1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple set of formulas.

```
=find()    
=left()    
=Right()
```

[Here are the formula's I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRJQE.png)

[Here are the results of those formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVuLF.png)

Basically, the find() formula allows you to find where the ""Http:" is in your string. Left() allows you to print() everything to the left of that. Right() lets you get everything to the right.